# Implementing a log viewer with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, user-interface, scroll

I seek advice for the best approach to implement a console-log viewer with WPF.

It should match the following criteria:

- fast scrolling with 100.000+ lines
- Some entries (like stacktraces) should be foldable
- long items wrap
- the list can be filtered by different criteria (searching, tags, etc)
- when at the end, it should keep scrolling when new items are added
- Line-elements can contain some sort of addition formatting like hyperlinks and occurrence counter

In general I have something in mind like the console window of FireBug and Chrome.

I played around with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization?msg=4350764#xx4350764xx) but I didn't make much progress, because...
- the datagrid can't handle different item heights
- the scroll position is only updated after releasing the scrollbar (which is completely unacceptable).

I'm pretty sure, I need some form of virtualization and would love to follow the MVVM pattern.

Any help or pointers are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you need to implement your own log viewer? This is kind of re-inventing the wheel... Can you use 3rd party tools to view your logs? For example, you can open [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) and it will capture logs that are sent via Windows API. you can then broadcast logs that will be captured in the tool, for easy browsing and filtering

Comment: Excellent question. I need this component as part of an existing WPF application. We already have a "console" which is implemented as a frustratingly slow TextBox. But now we need the additional features I described. I'm very happy to reusing existing commercial or free non-GPL components.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

I should start selling these WPF samples instead of giving them out for free. =P

[image]

- Virtualized UI (Using `VirtualizingStackPanel`) which provides incredibly good performance (even with 200000+ items)
- Fully MVVM-friendly.
- `DataTemplate`s for each kind of `LogEntry` type. These give you the ability to customize as much as you want. I only implemented 2 kinds of LogEntries (basic and nested), but you get the idea. You may subclass `LogEntry` as much as you need. You may even support rich text or images.
- Expandable (Nested) Items.
- Word Wrap.
- You can implement filtering, etc. by using a `CollectionView`.
- WPF Rocks, just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.LogViewer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples"
    Title="LogViewer" Height="500" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="LogViewerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
        <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Index" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" Grid.Column="0"
                       FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Grid.Column="1"
                       FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,2,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="2"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CollapsibleLogEntry}">
        <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Index" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" Grid.Column="0"
                       FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Grid.Column="1"
                       FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,2,0" />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="2"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contents}" Style="{StaticResource LogViewerStyle}"
                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          x:Name="Contents" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="Expander" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Contents" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Content" Value="-"/>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat='{}{0} Items'}"
               DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource LogViewerStyle}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**
*(Notice that most of it is just boilerplate to support the example (generate random entries)*

```
public partial class LogViewer : Window
{
    private string TestData = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
    private List<string> words;
    private int maxword;
    private int index;

    public ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }

    public LogViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        random = new Random();
        words = TestData.Split(' ').ToList();
        maxword = words.Count - 1;

        DataContext = LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>();
        Enumerable.Range(0, 200000)
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => LogEntries.Add(GetRandomEntry()));

        Timer = new Timer(x => AddRandomEntry(), null, 1000, 10);
    }

    private System.Threading.Timer Timer;
    private System.Random random;
    private void AddRandomEntry()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => LogEntries.Add(GetRandomEntry())));
    }

    private LogEntry GetRandomEntry()
    {
        if (random.Next(1,10) > 1)
        {
            return new LogEntry
            {
                Index = index++,
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Message = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(5, random.Next(10, 50))
                                                     .Select(x => words[random.Next(0, maxword)])),
            };
        }

        return new CollapsibleLogEntry
        {
            Index = index++,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Message = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(5, random.Next(10, 50))
                                                 .Select(x => words[random.Next(0, maxword)])),
            Contents = Enumerable.Range(5, random.Next(5, 10))
                                 .Select(i => GetRandomEntry())
                                 .ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

**Data Items:**

```
public class LogEntry : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class CollapsibleLogEntry: LogEntry
{
    public List<LogEntry> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

**PropertyChangedBase:**

```
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Did you just write this?! This is truly amazing. I just tested it and it's pretty much the perfect answer to my question. It looks like fleshing out the details should be straight foward. I'm blown away. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you would be for hire to answer questions like that once in a while, I would be very happy to pay. :-)

Comment: One problem I have found is that when I scrolled the mouse wheel on a  nested item, the view did not scroll.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun that's because of the nested `ScrollViewer`s, you can try setting a different `ControlTemplate` to the nested `ItemsControl`s.

Comment: Or you can just hook up the nested ScrollViewer's scroll to the parent scrollviewer. Shouldn't be that hard. The only problem here is you can't copy paste the log since it is a textblock. But easy fix it make it a textbox and readonly. :P

Comment: @HighCore I have implemented something similar to the above, but using MVVM. I have a `LogView` and `LogViewModel` with Caliburn handling the `DataContext` for me.  I have simply replaced `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...` with `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}" ...` but I am getting a binding error `Cannot set Expression. It is marked as 'NonShareable' and has already been used` which clearly suggests the `DataContext` is not set correctly - it is not obvious to me why though - any thoughts?

Comment: If you have some time I have asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29378925/626442...

Comment: When LogEntry message is too large (many rows) I cannot scroll among its rows. I mean, scroll jumps from a LogEntry to the next. How can I make the scrollviewer scroll among the lowest level?

Comment: Thanks for WOW solution but, only problem is scroll to bottom is not automatic, Can you please provide the fix for that ?

Comment: some warning: Grid.IsSharedSizeScope does not have any effect here. For a possible solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924079/9963147

Comment: I don't think this will handle 10,000 logs per second

Comment: @user1034912 if you have 10k logs per second you clearly have a much bigger problem than just showing them in a log viewer application.

Answer (score 27):

HighCore answer is perfect, but I guess it's missing this requirement:"when at the end, it should keep scrolling when new items are added".

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315242/3606250) answer, you can do this:

In the main ScrollViewer (inside the DockPanel), add the event:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
```

Cast the event source to do the auto scroll:

```
    private bool AutoScroll = true;
    private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // User scroll event : set or unset autoscroll mode
        if (e.ExtentHeightChange == 0)
        {   // Content unchanged : user scroll event
            if ((e.Source as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset == (e.Source as ScrollViewer).ScrollableHeight)
            {   // Scroll bar is in bottom
                // Set autoscroll mode
                AutoScroll = true;
            }
            else
            {   // Scroll bar isn't in bottom
                // Unset autoscroll mode
                AutoScroll = false;
            }
        }

        // Content scroll event : autoscroll eventually
        if (AutoScroll && e.ExtentHeightChange != 0)
        {   // Content changed and autoscroll mode set
            // Autoscroll
            (e.Source as ScrollViewer).ScrollToVerticalOffset((e.Source as ScrollViewer).ExtentHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AutoScroll variable is an exception

Comment: Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: This doesn't work and occasionally gives me a null exception on e.source