# Passing Data from WinForm to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I'm looking to pass data to a WPF window from a WinForm and receive a message back from the WPF window.

My code is a mix of random online tutorials and HighCore's [log viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743804/implementing-a-log-viewer-with-wpf/16745054#16745054). I have a WinForm that launches my new WPF window in the following fashion:

```
private void openTransactionViewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var transactionViewWindow = new TransactionViewer.MainWindow();
     ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(transactionViewWindow);
     transactionViewWindow.Show();
     transactionViewWindow.Test = "test";   // testing out data passing
     transactionViewWindow.AddTest();
  }
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<Session> SessionList { get; set; }
  public string Test{ get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     SessionList = new ObservableCollection<Session>();

     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 0, EndLine = 1, Message = "some message" });
     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 2, EndLine = 3, Message = "another message" });

     SessionItems.ItemsSource = SessionList;  // the ItemsControl
  }

  public void AddTest()
  {
     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 4, EndLine = 5, Message = Test });
  }
}

public class Session : PropertyChangedBase
{
   public int BeginLine { get; set; }
   public int EndLine { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

where `PropertyChangedBase` inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have an ItemsControl bound to `Message`. My output looks like:

> some message
>   another message
>   test

"Data passing" is successful! Eventually, when the WPF window loads I want to pass a `List<Session>` from my WinForm that will be used to populate the ItemsControl. I also want to have a button on the WinForm that will send a List to repopulate/refresh the data in the WPF. From the current behaviour I think this will be possible even with my current, simple implementation (just updating `SessionList`).

Is there a more appropriate way of doing this? Events, for example? Do I need to fire off an event in order to tell my WinForm that the WPF has successfully added all `Session` objects, or whenever a user clicks on a specific one?
Any benefit to using MVVM here?

I've been developing for WinForms for a while and finding the transition to WPF quite confusing. Hopefully someone can help out with some guidance or code examples.

Edit: for future reference, a decent MVVM tutorial targeted to people like me can be found here: http://jpreecedev.com/2013/06/08/wpf-mvvm-for-winforms-devs-part-1-of-5/

Comment: So you have WPF and WinForms in the same process? Same assembly?

Comment: @JeffBridgman yes, they're also in the same solution. I added a WPF Custom Control Library project to my existing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach seems OK to me. It's not perfect, but it is workable enough.

An optimal approach, IMO, would be to create a ViewModel for the WPF Window, instead of directly referencing the `Window` itself when passing data back and forth.

The idea is:

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
   public TransactionViewerViewModel TransactionViewer {get;set;}

   //... other code...

   //Form constructor:
   public MyForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

      //Create ViewModel:
      TransactionViewer = new TransactionViewerViewModel();
   }

   private void openTransactionViewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Create WPF View:
      var transactionViewWindow = new TransactionViewer.MainWindow();

      //Interop code
      ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(transactionViewWindow);

      //Set DataContext:
      transactionViewWindow.DataContext = TransactionViewer;     

      //Show Window:
      transactionViewWindow.Show();

      //Call methods on the ViewModel, rather than the View:
      TransactionViewer.Test = "test";   // testing out data passing
      TransactionViewer.AddTest();
   }
}
```

So, the ViewModel would be something like:

```
public class TransactionViewerViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<Session> SessionList { get; set; }
  public string Test{ get; set; }

  public TransactionViewerViewModel()
  {
     SessionList = new ObservableCollection<Session>();

     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 0, EndLine = 1, Message = "some message" });
     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 2, EndLine = 3, Message = "another message" });

  }

  public void AddTest()
  {
     SessionList.Add(new Session() { BeginLine = 4, EndLine = 5, Message = Test });
  }
}
```

This achieves a perfect separation between the WPF UI and the actual data / business logic, to the point that you can even create Unit Tests for your ViewModel.

And, since you're setting the ViewModel as the Window's `DataContext`, you will need to access all your ViewModel properties via DataBinding, rather than procedural code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SessionList}"/>
```

Then, you may want to introduce `delegates` or `events` in the ViewModel, and listen to these in your Form, thus achieving `WPF => winforms` communication.

Comment: HighCore to the rescue! Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. (I've basically learned WPF from you :P)

Comment: A followup... is the solution described [here](http://blogmarq.co.uk/index.php/launch-wpf-window-from-winforms-host/) acceptable for use with the MVVM for WPF -> WinForm communication?

Comment: @valsidalv yes, it uses parts of the Prism Framework (which is the official MVVM Framework from Microsoft), to send "messages" between WPF and winforms in a decoupled way. That is the best solution, IMO, though it adds some overhead in terms of architecture and structural design.