# Can't update MainWindow textbox from another class WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Why does my textbox fail to update when I try to update it from another class?

I've instantiated the MainWindow class in my Email class, but when I try to do

```
main.trending.Text += emailText;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you have instantiated a MainWindow inside Email class then you have updated the textbox in THAT window not the MainWindow of the entire application, you will need to pass a reference to the already instantiated MainWindow into the Email class.

Comment: I recommend to use data binding. When the data change the PropertyChange event will be fired. You will have less trouble with binding.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your data.

**Model**

```
public class YourData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _textBoxData;

  public YourData()
  {
  }

  public string TextBoxData
  {
      get { return _textBoxData; }
      set
      {
          _textBoxData = value;
          // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxData");
      }
  }

  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

}

**XAML Binding**

1. Set data context in Codebehind

   this.DataContext = YourData;
2. Bind Property

   ```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

See @sa_ddam213 comment. Dont do something like `MainWindow main = new MainWindow();` inside Email class. Instead, pass the MainWindow object you already have.
Following codes will work:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public void MethodWhereYouCreateEmailClass()
    {
        Email email = new Email;
        email.Main = this;
    }
}

public class Email
{
    public MainWindow main;

    public void MethodWhereYouSetTrendingText()
    {
        main.trending.Text += emailText;
    }
}
```

But I dont say that is best practice. I just try to keep it close to your existing code i guess.

Comment: other user happened to have similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085272/function-call-works-when-called-internally-from-in-its-control-but-not-externall/).