# ObservableCollection triggering too many CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code below which perform async update of an **`ObservableCollection`** of Messages which are collected over an Ethernet Connection

**`ObservableCollection`**

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<MsgDisplayViewModel> _rxGridMessages;
public ObservableCollection<MsgDisplayViewModel> RxGridMessages
{
    get { return _rxGridMessages; }
}
```

**`Action`**

```
_rxMsgUpdater = new Action<RxMessage>((RxMessage msg) =>
    {
        if (_rxGridMessages.Count < 2000)
        {
            _rxGridMessages.Add(new MsgDisplayViewModel(msg, DataCollection.DataBase));
        }
        else
        {
            var dispmsg = new MsgDisplayViewModel(msg, DataCollection.DataBase);
            _rxGridMessages[index++ % _rxGridMessages.Count] = dispmsg;
        }
    }
);
```

**`BeginInvoke`** called by Background thread from **`RxEventHandler`**

```
    private void RxEventHandler(RxMessage msg)
    {
        UiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(_rxMsgUpdater, DispatcherPriority.Normal, msg);
    }
```

**`XAML`**

```
<DataGrid Name="TraceGrid" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding MyVm.RxGridMessages, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}"
     SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" FontSize="10" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" BorderThickness="1"   EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"                        
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
```

...

The UI is fine and good as long as the background thread is calling the **`RxEventHandler`** something like 20 times per second.
Once I put the real traffic in, the **`RxEventHandler`** is called something like 1000 times per second.

So I tried something by extending the **`ObservableCollection`**, I started collecting the changed items on the base **`OnCollectionChanged`** of **`ObservableCollection`** and trigger every 500 ms a **`CollectionChanged`** event.
It obviously threw **`RangeNotSupportedException`** and I had to use the following instead,

```
    try
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, addedItems, itemaddedindex));
    }
    catch (System.NotSupportedException)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
```

The problem is that the collection is rebuild and there is some delay before it gets displayed. If Collection item count is low it is pretty quick. But when it is 1000 or so then it takes some seconds.

I am feeding this to the datagrid as shown above and I have enabled **`Virtualization`** as well. Now I have done a lot of googling and I have not found someone with a work around for this problem.
Can anybody advice me on this?

I have done some profiling and the CPU hog is **`PresentationFramework.ni.dll`** and it seems related to the numerous **`CollectionChanged`** events.
Right now I have something responsive but at the cost of limiting the Collection count. This is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  Core issue is that you designed a user interface that's completely unusable to a human.  Nobody can read a thousands lines of text a second, the info you display is just not useful.  Create a usable UI where, say, the user can look at a frozen snapshot of a section of messages at his leisure.  And the BeginInvoke() problem automatically solves itself as well.

Comment: Yes, that I agree, but then I am working on an Application which deals with Bus (Ethernet, Flexray etc) traces. Which means I need to load these messages on the UI so that the user can examine. So the user just checks the messages and filters the one he is interested then he scrolls down and checks some other messages. So the update has to be there. The thing I am looking for is a compromise of real time update and human usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new in Visual Studio 2015

```
BulkObservableCollection
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd867973.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Due to the nature of this problem, you should use some type of processing queue and then create a handler that handles the processing sepeerately. Furthermore because of the sheer amount of data you are working with, you should either use a timer to query for new updates every x seconds/minutes and refresh datagrid that way , or you should use some type of virtualizing panel that can handle the sheer amount of data being passed into it(ListView/GridView)