# Display NLog trace in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, nlog

I whant to display `NLog` trace into `RichTextBox` at the same time when app executes

```
logger.Trace("This is a Trace message");
logger.Debug("This is a Debug message");
logger.Info("This is an Info message");
logger.Warn("This is a Warn message");
logger.Error("This is an Error message");
logger.Fatal("This is a Fatal error message");
```

Has `NLog` any global event so it is possible to use it and populate `RichTextBox`?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_RichTextBoxTarget.htm

Comment: Or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/RichTextBox-target

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743804/implementing-a-log-viewer-with-wpf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have to install `https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Windows.Forms`

After this use `NLog.Windows.Forms;`

And finally add the code

```
 private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget target = new NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget();
            target.Name = "RichTextBox";
            target.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message}";
            target.ControlName = "richTextBoxMainLog";
            target.FormName = "FormMain";
            target.AutoScroll = true;
            target.MaxLines = 10000;
            target.UseDefaultRowColoringRules = false;
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(
                new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule(
                    "level == LogLevel.Trace", // condition
                    "DarkGray", // font color
                    "Control", // background color
                    FontStyle.Regular
                )
            );
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Debug", "Gray", "Control"));
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Info", "ControlText", "Control"));
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Warn", "DarkRed", "Control"));
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Error", "White", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));
            target.RowColoringRules.Add(new RichTextBoxRowColoringRule("level == LogLevel.Fatal", "Yellow", "DarkRed", FontStyle.Bold));

            AsyncTargetWrapper asyncWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper();
            asyncWrapper.Name = "AsyncRichTextBox";
            asyncWrapper.WrappedTarget = target;

            SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(asyncWrapper, LogLevel.Trace);
        }
```

Also you need to configure NLog target.

```
 <target xsi:type="RichTextBox"
            name="target2"
            layout="${message} ${rtb-link:link text in config}"

            formName="Form1"
            ControlName="richTextBoxMainLog"
            autoScroll="true"
            maxLines="20"

            allowAccessoryFormCreation="false"
            messageRetention="OnlyMissed"

            supportLinks="true"

            useDefaultRowColoringRules="true" />
```

Download the sample project and test it https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms