# WPF Log File Viewer Component

Tags: wpf, logging, catel

I am looking for a WPF component to load log files and show them in my application. It should at least provide some sort of filtering, a search and color coding.

The only thing I found that looked promising was Orc.LogViewer. I was however unable to simply use this as a viewer for existing log files, as there seems to be no functionality to load files. It only works with active log listeners.

Comment: How about this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743804/implementing-a-log-viewer-with-wpf ? With some tweaking you could add search functionality and colors yourself. Or do you really want a standalone library?

Comment: I am looking for a low effort solution with a standalone library

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the LogViewer app created by the same company. See https://github.com/wildgums/logviewer

Comment: This application doesn't even run when compiled. It immediately crashes with an access to a disposed object. But I am anyway looking for a component I can integrate rather than a complete application.