# Programmatically scrolling a ScrollViewer with a timer becomes jerky

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, user-interface

Animating the scrolling in a `ScrollViewer` seems to be a common task. I implemented it using a timer, similar to the approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2984803/938695). This method was working great, it was very smooth and looked perfect.

However, now that the complexity and number of objects contained within my `ScrollViewer` has increased, the animation looks very jerky. I find this odd because it works fine if I scroll manually.

```
    public void ShiftLeft(int speed = 11)
    {
        CustomTimer timer = new CustomTimer(); //DispatchTimer with "life"
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5);
        timer.Tick += ((sender, e) =>
        {
            scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(
                scrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset - (scrollViewer1.ScrollableWidth / (gridColumnCount - 3) / speed));
            if (scrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset == 0) //cant scroll any more
                ((CustomTimer)sender).Stop();
            ((CustomTimer)sender).life++;
            if (((CustomTimer)sender).life >= speed) //reached destination
                ((CustomTimer)sender).Stop();
        });
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Is there a problem with my approach that is causing this weird jerking? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried asynchronous operation? A System.Timers.Timer is asynchronous is by default. You'd then just have to handle the cross thread operation for the UI. But that's not difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CompositionTarget.Rendering` will be a better fit for animating things as it fires every time a frame is about to be rendered. Try something like this instead:

```
    public void Shift(ScrollViewer target, double speed = 11, double distance = 20)
    {
        double startOffset = target.HorizontalOffset;
        double destinationOffset = target.HorizontalOffset + distance;

        if (destinationOffset < 0)
        {
            destinationOffset = 0;
            distance = target.HorizontalOffset;
        }

        if (destinationOffset > target.ScrollableWidth)
        {
            destinationOffset = target.ScrollableWidth;
            distance = target.ScrollableWidth - target.HorizontalOffset;
        }

        double animationTime = distance / speed;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

        EventHandler renderHandler = null;

        renderHandler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            double elapsed = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;

            if (elapsed >= animationTime)
            {
                target.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(destinationOffset);
                CompositionTarget.Rendering -= renderHandler;
            }

            target.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(startOffset + (elapsed * speed));
        };

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += renderHandler;
    }
```

EDIT: added range checking

Use negative distance values to scroll left.

EDIT 2:

You might want to use this `CompositionTargetEx` implementation instead of `CompositionTarget`, as it will only fire when a new frame will actually be drawn by the render thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16334423/612510

EDIT 3:

Since you are on WPF (and not Silverlight, like I am more accustomed to) you might use the `Stopwatch` class to measure elapsed seconds instead of my `DateTime.Now` method.

Comment: That's MUCH better. Thanks for that. I was using a timer event like @Austin and it was stop-start jerky. I'm running more or less the same code now inside a CompositionTarget.Rendering handler (but compensating for the variable time-since-last-render-update) and it's silky smooth!

Comment: @Jon could you share your code? i've implemented this and its still a bit janky