# How to auto scroll to the bottom of a VScrollBar

Tags: c#, winforms

in a fDisplaySMSList Form , i have a pictureBox and VScrollBar

[image: Image1]

every data come in PictureBox the VScrollBar not automatically scroll to the bottom to new data. how to auto scroll to the bottom in VScrollBar?

------------------------Edit

i have a form SMS, like this,

[image]

when the new inbox or compose come in the form, the scroll always in the top, here the pict.

[image]

and the question is how to form VScrollBar go down when i sent or receive message like this,

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically scroll ScrollViewer - only if the user did not change scroll position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984803/how-to-automatically-scroll-scrollviewer-only-if-the-user-did-not-change-scrol)

Comment: @Sibster, not a dup, based on app icon, this one is in winform not wpf

Comment: can you use Try using item.EnsureVisible() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [ScrollBar.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

Also try calling [ListView.EnsureVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the last ListViewItem, to which you want to scroll

Comment: ScrollBar.Value is 0 , how to set it to bottom when the data come? @ArsenMkrt

Comment: can you calculate image width, and set value to scrollbar.Maximum - image.height?